# VLookup function in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm very new to VBA, yet I still find myself writing a UDF for excel and part of that process requires that a value be pulled from another sheet that is open in the same workbook. I don't know what I'm doing obviously, but I'm hoping someone else can point me in the right direction.

A sheet called "VIAL TYPES" has the data that I need in the 7th column. 
For the purpose of this question, I would just like to print the value of VLookup in cell G9.

To run the function, I would manually write in the VialType in an adjacent cell. I expect the Vlookup function to recognize the type entered into cell (=VTEST(cellIwrotethevialtypein)), find it's match in the "VIAL TYPES" sheet and then print the value in the 7th column back in the active sheet. Basically, I want it to do exactly what VLOOKUP does, I just need this to work in vba so that I can execute additional things with the value.

I get #Value! in the cell now.

```
    Function VTEST(VialType As String)

    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("G9").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(VialType, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("VIAL TYPES").Range("A1:A309"), 7, False)

    End Function
```

Comment: There are not 7 columns in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("VIAL TYPES").Range("A1:A309") the 7 is dynamic on the range in the second criterion.  You  need to expand your range to include the column from which you want the value to be returned. `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("VIAL TYPES").Range("A1:G309")`

Comment: Also you want to change the first part to `VTEST` instead of `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("G9").Value` to make the UDF return the value to the cell in which you place the formula.  A UDF in itself cannot change the value of another cell.

Comment: The trick to `VLookUp` is to make sure that the value you are searching for is always to the left of the value you want to return. Your code is looking in 1 column: A. If column A is the column that contains the `VialType`, and you want to return the corresponding value from column 7, then you must use `.Range("A1:G309")`. However, if your searched column were column B, then not only would you change the range to `.Range("B1:G309")`, but you would also return column 6 of your range (eeven though its the 7th column on the sheet).

Comment: Why the UDF for a `=VLOOKUP()`?

Comment: Y'all solved my problem in like 3 minutes, u da real mvp.

Comment: I still question your use of a UDF. Not very often they are necessary over a built in formula, especially not when you are self proclaimed "very new to VBA".

Comment: Kyle, from here, I'm storing it as a variable and making some additional declarations about the data. I just needed to see that this section of the final program actually works, which you all made happen by being great people.